# ¿Cómo correr un proyecto nodejs con una tarea programada en Ubuntu?

Tags: nodejs, linux, mongodb, ubuntu, crontab

Tengo un proyecto de node js en donde realizo una actualización a la base de datos (una base de datos mongodb). Todo anda correcto; me funciona perfecto cuando corro el proyecto por la terminal. Sin embargo, es necesario que ese actualizador corra todos los días a una misma hora, así que hice un archivo bash para que al ser ejecutado corriera el comando exacto para hacer funcionar el proyecto cuando se llame; ese script si se ejecuta por terminal también lo hace bien. Pensé que hacer un crontab para que cada día ejecutara ese script sería una buena idea, pero cuando el crontab realiza la tarea no funciona. Hice que el contrab me escribiera el error en un archivo para saber el porqué y sale esto:

```
Proyecto/node_modules/mongodb/lib/admin.js:62
            session: options?.session,
                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿por qué cuando se realiza la tarea por crontab ocurre errores con la conexión con mongo? ¿No es posible hacer lo que quiero con crontab? Además, de no poderse hacer, ¿existe otra forma de programar la tarea todos los días y que funcione?

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar un [repro] del script que se está ejecutando?

Comment: ¿Puedes editar la pregunta añadiendo el script de bash?

Comment: podría ser posible que la version de node con la que corres el script desde bash sea diferente a la version de node con la que la corres manualmente? a mi ese error del punto me ha salido cuando uso una version vieja de node sobre un código reciente

Comment: sí, me fijé y ese era el problema. Muchas gracias!